# New users broken down by medium totals more than new users

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If I grab a breakdown of new users by medium for the month of September and total up the individual rows I get a total of 9,659:

```
Medium        New Users
(none)        1,307
Online other    1
cpc            3,130
display        339
email            29
organic        4,032
referral        821
```

Query:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-09-01&end-date=2016-09-30&metrics=ga%3AnewUsers&dimensions=ga%3Amedium

But if I grab the total number of new users for the same time period it give me 9,654 which is 5 less:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-09-01&end-date=2016-09-30&metrics=ga%3AnewUsers

(I've removed the ID from these queries as advised by google when sharing the links publicly)

If I use the metric ga:sessions rather than ga:newUsers the numbers total up ok.

Comment: This really isn't coding related its more analytics understanding related you might want to try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DalmTo the first item under 'getting help' in the Core Reporting API docs is a link to stackoverflow: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/help